# How to blur an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, focus

I'm using JavaScript with HTML and I have a page that includes multiple iframes. I want to be able to blur some of these iframse (not hide then) so that users can see what is inside these frames but cannot click on them or type in them.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I guess you could use a transparent overlay within the iframe, and trigger it with JS in the parent window.

Comment: Or a semi-transparent overlay so that the contents are out of focus...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this may be what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/xcWcn/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="frame1-blocker" class="frame-blocker"></div>
<iframe id="frame1" src="http://google.com" style="width: 500px; height: 300px; padding: 0px; border: 0px;"/>
```

CSS:

```
.frame-blocker{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    position: absolute;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: That's a fade, no blur.

Answer (score 1):

```
iframe.contents().find('body').blur()
```

Comment: Does not work if the iframe is from different origin

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest positioning a transparent DIV over each "blurred" iFrame to prevent clock events propagating downward. iFrame tags themselves do not to my knowledge provide the functionality you want.

And for what it's worth, "blur" in Web parlance refers to moving the text cursor outside of a control!

Answer (score -1):

Here is a demo of a way using an overlay within the iframe:

```
#hidden {
    display: none;
}
iframe {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
a {
    color: #f00;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
}

<div>
    <a class="activate" rel="1">Active Test 1</a><br/>
    <a class="activate" rel="2">Active Test 2</a><br/>
    <a class="activate" rel="3">Active Test 3</a>
</div>
<iframe id="test1"></iframe>
<iframe id="test2"></iframe>
<iframe id="test3"></iframe>
<div id="hidden">
    <div id="overlay" style="display: none; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 100; background-color: #000;"></div>
    <div>
        <a href="http://www.yahoo.com/" target="_blank">http://www.yahoo.com/</a>
    </div>
</div>

$('iframe').each(function(){
    $(this).contents().find('body').append($('#hidden').html());
});
$('div a.activate').click(function(){
    $('iframe[id^=test]').contents().find('#overlay')
        .css('height','200px')
        .css('width','200px')
        .fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
    $('iframe#test'+this.rel).contents().find('#overlay')
        .css('height','0')
        .css('width','0')
        .fadeTo('fast', 1);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZTpXa/

Comment: Down-voted for answering a JavaScript question with jQuery. Fix and comment and I'll reverse my vote.

Comment: Right. Downvoting a six year old question based on using jQuery. You can have your downvote.